# Generic Unit of Work & (Extensible) Repositories Framework Generic Unit of Work & (Extensible) Repositories Framework with lazy loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

1. In my architect solution i have used the Generic Unit of Work & (Extensible) Repositories Framework Open Source from this link :
   https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/ 
   But the example code is not using lazy loading so i have active it in my project but it's not working ?

2.Normaly with entity framework (lazy loading mode is active) when we retrieve an object  there related object not retrived unitl we call some properties of his related object. But in my project with this framework and on lazy loading mode i dont have this result the related is automaticlay loaded when retrieve my parrent object  ? i need a help  ?

this is the constructor of my data context  :

```
 public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            _instanceId = Guid.NewGuid();
            //Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            //Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        }
```

And this is an Example of my Controller :

```
              //Loading agencies only (but not working because i get all the related objects)
        IList<Agency> Agence = AgencyService.Query().Select().ToList();

        Agency Ag = Agence[0];

        //Loads Agency company for particular Agency only (seperate SQL query) => also not working 
        Company company = Ag.Company;
```

Answer (score 0):

To set lazy loading active:

1. context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled should be true.
2. context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled should be true.
3. Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual. Context will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not define as virtual.

Comment: the lazy loading is active by default in entity framework we don't need to set Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled to true and all my navigation property are public and virtual. Is there a specific configuration when using generic repository ??

Comment: In the Entity Framework runtime, the default value of the LazyLoadingEnabled property in an instance of ObjectContext is false. However, if you use the Entity Framework tools to create a new model and the corresponding generated classes, the generated code will set LazyLoadingEnabled to true in the constructor of the generated object context.

Comment: It means, Database first approach then by default azyLoadingEnabled property is true. but code first we need to set in context constructer